# Pageshow event in Firefox not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, jquery-events

I am trying to find a cross-browser way to detect `pageshow` event, because in Firefox it doesn't fire every time. I am using this code to register `pageshow` callback:

```
 $(window).on('pageshow', callback);
```

This works great in Chrome, but in Firefox, callback is called only every third time after page refresh, and I suspect this happens due to caching. Now, similar thing happens with document `load` event in Firefox, but I found a way around:

```
var intervalCheck = setInterval(function() {
                if (document.readyState === "complete") {
                    clearInterval(intervalCheck);
                    callback();
                }
            }, 10);
```

This works great, is there maybe a similar thing for `pageshow` event ?

Comment: You missed the closing `'` of pageshow, is this the error or it is typo

Comment: what version of jquery are you using?

Comment: I forgot to say that this event handler works great in local environment, but in production(remote server), this issue happens.